# Schedule maintenance on github repository

Tags: github

I wanted to block PR merge on specific times (when there is something going on with our environment).

Merging a PR would auto-deploy build to our environments which will bring down env for some time with CI/CD in place.

I would also look at CI/CD pipeline to schedule maintenance but wanted to know if GitHub has something available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe GitHub has such a feature available.  If the PR meets the branch criteria, including passing any CI checks, then it can be merged by anybody with write access.

If you want to control when a PR is merged, then the best way to do this is to use a fork-based model and restrict the main repository to administrators and a bot.  Then you can configure the bot to merge pull requests when you'd like it to, since other users won't have access to merge.

Alternatively, you can rely on users to always explicitly deploy before merging using a bot of some sort and then not let the bot deploy if things are in a bad state.  That's the approach GitHub uses, and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Note: the GitHub [`dear-github/dear-github` issue 84](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/84) "Add feature to disable pull requests on a repositor" does [mention](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/84#issuecomment-1193074797=):

> For the time being we can block PRs for a limited time using the moderation section
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36747317/180594368-b1cb6402-1cab-40c9-906e-4f1ccc08d348.png]

Hence the warning:

```
An owner of this repository has limited the ability to open a pull request 
to users that are collaborators on this repository
```

Because of:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/81188/114829217-17e90080-9dcb-11eb-9dd4-69834e2b223e.png]

However:

> As "interaction" includes creating issues and more, the existing moderation feature cannot be used to disable only pull requests.
> Beyond lacking the necessary granularity, the "temporary interaction limits" are, well, temporary.

So this is really a (poor) workaround, pending a true implementation of the feature request.